# How do I prove that $A^{T} A$ is not invertible when n<m?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an $ \times $ matrix.
Prove that if $n < m$ then $A^{T}A$ is not invertible.

I know that when $Ax=0$ does not have trivial solution the matrix is not invertible.

So by my understanding I need to show that $x$ has a non trivial solution.

I have trouble proving this with out using dimensions and ranks since I have not yet learned those  in detail.

Comment: T is transpose.

Comment: Just use the relation between rank and invertibility. I have given an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A $n \times m$ matrix is a map from $\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. If $n<m$, then this linear map cannot be injective. Similarly, $A^T$ would be a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. This map cannot be surjective. So $A^{T}A$ would be a map from $\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.  This map is not bijective and hence an inverse cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $C(AB) \subset C(A)$ or $R(AB) \subset R(A)$. (C is column space and R is row space)

So $R(A^TA) \subset R(A)$. This means that rank of $A^TA$ is at most rank of $A$. But rank of $A$ is at most $min\{m,n\}=n$.

However, $A^TA$ is $m \times m$ matrix and rank is at most $n$ which is strictly less than $m$. Thus $A^TA$ cannot be invertible.